# In Angular how can I set a watch inside my directive that fires when the value of an attribute changes?

Tags: angularjs

If I have a directive call like this:

```
<mydirective data-pid="data.Id"></mydirective>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function ($compile) {    
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, Element, attrs, ngModel) {

        }
    }
});
```

Then in the link area of my directive how can I watch this attribute and do something if its value changes?

Comment: can you show me your directive code?

Comment: See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dHXXxsfLDq7yZ6tth6LV?p=preview) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pid: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('pid', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    console.log('pid changed', newValue);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### See this demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R9eFmPCIUQlDgecv4Fvy?p=preview).

Using `scope: {pid: '='}` you

> set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute

to quote line from [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile).

Comment: Thanks. I have a very similar question and will post that now.